# Pulling Unique Data from a Table A Certain Number of Times (Advanced)

Tags: excel-formula

I don't think this problem is actually very difficult. But I'm stumped. If you can take a look for me I'd really appreciate it.

Basically, I need to summarise all the labour hour costing for each month. I have a list of staff who, for their work each day, record the: jobs, codes for that job, and hours for that.

Sample Source Data:

```
Datestamp   Name    Job 1   Code 1  Hours
18/08/2017  Chainz Graham   247 - Dixon Stage 5 08-Other    
19/08/2017  Jury Herewini   252 - Kay Rd Cutdown    02-Roading  8:00:00
20/08/2017  Adam Young  247 - Dixon Stage 5 08-Other    3:00:00
21/08/2017  Adam Young  250 - 132 Kay Rd Subdivision    03-Stormwater   9:30:00
22/08/2017  Jury Herewini   250 - 132 Kay Rd Subdivision    03-Stormwater   
23/08/2017  Adam Young  250 - 132 Kay Rd Subdivision    02-Roading
```

At the end of each month I want to sum all the hours assigned to each code so that I end up with a tidy list.

Sample Desired Projected Data:

```
Adam Young  250 - 132 Kay Rd Subdivision    02-Roading  43
Adam Young  250 - 132 Kay Rd Subdivision    03-Stormwater   17
Adam Young  252 - Kay Rd Cutdown    03-Stormwater   40
Chainz Graham   250 - 132 Kay Rd Subdivision    02-Roading  38
Chainz Graham   250 - 132 Kay Rd Subdivision    03-Stormwater   42
Connor Herewini 250 - 132 Kay Rd Subdivision    06-Concrete 29
```

The difficult thing is that I only want the name, project and code to appear if the worker had hours assigned to that code for the month. So in the final list, I want three Adam's to appear if he worked on three different job codes, and so on for jobs and codes.

Please don't worry about the hours column, a simple SUMIF function can get that job done. I can also get the correct number of names to come up easily, but the project and code I'm having trouble with.

Here's a sample spreadsheet to work with below which you can download:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3g...ew?usp=sharing

You will see the method I am attempting by the intermediate data in the sheet. You may find a better solution and ditch that method altogether. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like a pivot table might do it for you? Although admittedly not a formula.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't download your spreadsheet so not sure how your data look like in there.  With the data provided here, I came up with this array formula (Please click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together)):

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$E$7,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$7=$G2,ROW($B$2:$B$7)),COUNTIF($G$2:$G2,$G2))-1,MATCH(H$1,$B$1:$E$1,0)),"")`

I had the formula entered into `cell H2` so please adjust it based on your layout.  You can then drag it to cover all other fields.  And here is the screenshot of how it looks like in the outcome:

[image]

P.S. `Hours column` may show in a different format and you will need to update that as well.  Hope this can help you get start with your task.

P.P.S. I assume you will have the name ready for lookup or match on `column G`.